# How to use curl's -u options with Advanced Rest Client?

Tags: rest, curl, advanced-rest-client

My curl request looks like this:

```
curl -u jdoe@example.com/token:6wiIBWbGkBMo1mRDMuVwkw1EPsNkeUj95PIz2akv \
https://obscura.zendesk.com/api/v2/users.json
```

How can I specify `-u` option value in chrome's `Advanced Rest Client`?

Answer (score 2):

Try to set a `Authorization` header with the value `jdoe@example.com/token:6wiIBWbGkBMo1mRDMuVwkw1EPsNkeUj95PIz2akv` encoded using Base64:

```
Authorization: Basic amRvZUBleGFtcGxlLmNvbS90b2tlbjo2d2lJQldiR2tCTW8xbVJETXVWd2t3MUVQc05rZVVqOTVQSXoyYWt2
```

Answer (score 2):

In the UI when you type in Authorisation header an editor will show up (in code view select basic type to open the editor and in form view press the pencil image on the right hand side of the value field).
In the pop-up you'll be asked to provide username and password. The app will encode the value for you and paste it in the value field.